# How to use map with a regular expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell

While trying to apply the regular expression below to each element in a list (test), I get an error. This is what I am trying to do in ghci

```
import Text.Regex.TDFA
let test = ["<lobbying_firm>The CrisCom Company</lobbying_firm>","<registration_year>2013</registration_year>"]
let regExp = "\\>(.)*\\<"
let result = map (=~ regExp :: String) test
```

How can I do this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close. The only problem is that your type signature will generate some trouble here. The type of `(=~ rexExp)` you want is probably `String -> String`. Indeed the type of the mapping function is a function that takes a `String` as parameter, and returns a `String` here. Not a `String` itself.

We can thus create a `map` with:

```
result = map ((=~ regExp) :: String -> String) test
```

This produces:

```
Prelude Text.Regex.TDFA> map ((=~ regExp) :: String -> String) test
[">The CrisCom Company</",">2013</"]
```

That being said, I strongly advice *not* to parse HTML, XML, JSON, etc. with a regex. Indeed [*regexes can not parse HTML*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and other recursive languages. This is the consequence of the [*Pumping lemma for regular languages* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages). You can never *fully* parse HTML. You might indeed parse some sublanguages, etc. But even then the regex will easily get (very) complicated. You therefore better use a library like [**`tagsoup`** [hackage]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup), or a scraper library like [**`scalpel`** [hackage]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scalpel).